# Matlab - remove white areas

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

So I am trying to create a panoramic image out of 20 images and have given up trying to use Mathsworks example as I am getting no where. So I deicded to find matching pairs of images manually and then to try and stitch them. However, the output has a very large white border and is included when I stitch them.

Here are the images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgE2M.jpg

And heres the stitched image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1Yfa.jpg

```
clc;
clear;
close all;

% Load images.
buildingDir = fullfile('C:\Users\hayes\Documents\YEAR 2\CI285 Functional Programming\RonanHayes_AssignmentTwo\imageTry3');
%buildingDir = fullfile(toolboxdir('vision'), 'visiondata', 'building');
buildingScene = imageDatastore(buildingDir);

% Display images to be stitched
montage(buildingScene.Files);

% Read the first image from the image set.
I = readimage(buildingScene, 1);

% Initialize features for I(1)
grayImage = rgb2gray(I);
points = detectSURFFeatures(grayImage);
[features, points] = extractFeatures(grayImage, points);



% Initialize all the transforms to the identity matrix. Note that the
% projective transform is used here because the building images are fairly
% close to the camera. Had the scene been captured from a further distance,
% an affine transform would suffice.
numImages = numel(buildingScene.Files);
%tforms(numImages) = projective2d(eye(3));
tforms(numImages) = projective2d(eye(3));

% Initialize variable to hold image sizes.
imageSize = zeros(numImages,2);

% Iterate over remaining image pairs
for n = 2:numImages

    % Store points and features for I(n-1).
    pointsPrevious = points;
    featuresPrevious = features;

    % Read I(n).
    I = readimage(buildingScene, n);

    % Convert image to grayscale.
    grayImage = rgb2gray(I);
    %figure(3), imshow(grayImage);

    % Save image size.
    imageSize(n,:) = size(grayImage);

    % Detect and extract SURF features for I(n).
    points = detectSURFFeatures(grayImage);
    [features, points] = extractFeatures(grayImage, points);

    % Find correspondences between I(n) and I(n-1).
    % ORIGINAL CODE
    indexPairs = matchFeatures(features, featuresPrevious, 'Unique', true);
    %matchedPoints = points(indexPairs(:,1), :);
    %matchedPointsPrev = pointsPrevious(indexPairs(:,2), :);

    % ALTERED
    %indexPairs = matchFeatures(features, featuresPrevious, 'Unique', true);
    matchedPoints = points(indexPairs(:,1),:);
    matchedPointsPrev = pointsPrevious(indexPairs(:,2),:);


    %indexPairs = matchFeatures(features, featuresPrevious, 'Unique', true) ;
    %matchedPoints = points(indexPairs(1:2, 1));
    %matchedPointsPrev = pointsPrevious(indexPairs(1:2, 2));

    % Estimate the transformation between I(n) and I(n-1).

    % WHY IS IT CHANGING POINTS WHEN I INCLUDE THIS?

  tforms(n) = estimateGeometricTransform(matchedPoints, matchedPointsPrev,...
'projective', 'Confidence', 99.9, 'MaxNumTrials', 4000);


    % Compute T(n) * T(n-1) * ... * T(1)
    tforms(n).T = tforms(n).T * tforms(n-1).T;
end

% Compute the output limits  for each transform
for i = 1:numel(tforms)
    [xlim(i,:), ylim(i,:)] = outputLimits(tforms(i), [1 imageSize(i,2)], [1 imageSize(i,1)]);
end

avgXLim = mean(xlim, 2);

[~, idx] = sort(avgXLim);

centerIdx = floor((numel(tforms)+1)/2);

centerImageIdx = idx(centerIdx);

Tinv = invert(tforms(centerImageIdx));

for i = 1:numel(tforms)
    tforms(i).T = tforms(i).T * Tinv.T;
end

for i = 1:numel(tforms)
    [xlim(i,:), ylim(i,:)] = outputLimits(tforms(i), [1 imageSize(i,2)], [1 imageSize(i,1)]);
end

maxImageSize = max(imageSize);

% Find the minimum and maximum output limits
xMin = min([1; xlim(:)]);
xMax = max([maxImageSize(2); xlim(:)]);

yMin = min([1; ylim(:)]);
yMax = max([maxImageSize(1); ylim(:)]);

% Width and height of panorama.
width  = round(xMax - xMin);
height = round(yMax - yMin);

% Initialize the "empty" panorama.
panorama = zeros([height width 3], 'like', I);

blender = vision.AlphaBlender('Operation', 'Binary mask', 'MaskSource', 'Input port');

% Create a 2-D spatial reference object defining the size of the panorama.
xLimits = [xMin xMax];
yLimits = [yMin yMax];
panoramaView = imref2d([height width], xLimits, yLimits);

% Create the panorama.
for i = 1:numImages

    I = readimage(buildingScene, i);

    % Transform I into the panorama.
    warpedImage = imwarp(I, tforms(i), 'OutputView', panoramaView);

    % Generate a binary mask.
    mask = imwarp(true(size(I,1),size(I,2)), tforms(i), 'OutputView', panoramaView);

    % Overlay the warpedImage onto the panorama.
    panorama = step(blender, panorama, warpedImage, mask);
end

figure, imshow(panorama)
```

The stitched image looks correct, bar the white border blocking them connecting. So I dont know how to go about this

Comment: What I assume is that the white border is interfering with the stitching algorithm. Therefore, I ran your code after cropping the white border around the original images and this is what I get: https://imgur.com/6NQw72C. There is no more white space between the images

Comment: @ammportal Looks good, the other problem I am having now though is I've been saving the stitched image using imwrite so it crops the white automatically. But this leaves a black border instead. And then picks up the black border as matched features. Is there any way around it apart from like you've done (manually crop it). If there was a way to remove pure black/white pixels from being detected would it work?

Comment: I am not so knowledgable about image analysis although what I gather from the help for `imwrite` is that you can specify the background color while saving as png or jpeg.. maybe that would help you

Comment: ahhh ok i will look into it

Comment: @ammportal how did you crop it? just imcrop? Is there a way to use imcrop on multiple locations not just rectangluar/square

Comment: I actually manually cropped the image. Cropping by definition only works at one location. However again going through the help for `imcrop`, I see that there are options to specify the rectangle size and its position.